# 2 argument Function dealing with two pairs of parameters at once?

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing

What allows us to pass 2 different pairs of parameters into the function? I understand  `hours = convertTime(0, 23)`being passed in, but at what point does the program pass in  `minutes = convertTime(0, 59)`. When does the function call the second parameter set to be passed in `(minutes = convertTime(0, 59)?`

**heres the code:**

```
def convertTime(low, high):
    value = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    while value < low or value > high:
        print("Value out of range")
        value = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    return value


def main():
    print("Enter a time in hours and then minutes")
    hours = convertTime(0, 23)
    minutes = convertTime(0, 59)
    print("{} hours and {} minutes".format(hours, minutes))

main()
```

**Heres an example input/output:**

```
Enter a time in hours and then minutes
Enter a value: 12
Enter a value: 32
12 hours and 32 minutes
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You function `convertTime` takes two parameters and is given two, what is the problem? Are you struggling to understand why a function can be called twice?

Comment: I understand that you need to know when the first call end and the second call begin. In that case, I suggest you use a print call in the middle where you put a message about the new call.

Comment: I know that functions can be called twice, but im unsure at when the program knows when to call the 'minutes' parameters after the 'hours' parameters are passed through

Comment: The calls to `convertTime` are made in the order you wrote in `main`. So first `convertTime(0, 23)` is called, and when that returns and the `hours` value is saved then `convertTime(0, 59)` is called. `convertTime` contains a `while` loop that keeps looping until the user gives valid input, so if the user never gives valid input then `convertTime` won't ever return.